# How to make term and condition activity in an Android application in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sharedpreferences

I have developed an application and I want to make my 1st page like a terms and conditions activity in which the activity shows only first time after installing. And then if the user accepts it never shows on that device again. If the user rejects the terms and conditions activity it will be showing every time the application starts.

My question is "how can I implement the code?"

Comment: Use shared preference, check the value everytime when screen calls and check whether the check-box is checked or not, if yes then hide the activity otherwise show it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Show it in `AlertDialog` and put the result (Accept or Decline) at the `SharedPreferences` as `boolean` value. Then just check key value every time you start your app.

```
final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
boolean agreed = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("agreed",false);
if (!agreed) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setTitle("License agreement")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("agreed", true);
                editor.commit();
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", null)
        .setMessage(text)
        .show();
}
```